# How to create a rake rule that matches files from different folders?

Tags: c, gcc, rake

I need to create a rake rule where I compile each C file in the 'src' folder to a corresponding file in the 'obj' folder. In make this is achieved with:

```
obj/%.o: src/%.c
```

I've been trying to figure out how this can be done in rake, but couldn't find a solution. Here's the rake code:

```
SOURCES = Rake::FileList["src/*.c"]
OBJECTS = SOURCES.ext(".o").pathmap("obj/%f")

task :binary => OBJECTS do
    sh "gcc #{OBJECTS} --shared -o TARGET"
end

rule '.o' => '.c' do |task|
    sh "gcc -c src/#{task.source}"
end

task :default => :binary
```

When this code is run, the following error is thrown:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'obj/cx.o'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The following rake code works:

```
rule '.o' => ->(t){t.pathmap("src/%f").ext(".c")} do |task|
    sh "gcc -c #{task.source} -o #{task.name}"
end
```